# Zip a file in Cyangenmod Android from adb shell

Tags: android, shell, zip, adb

I have navigated to a file on my phone using adb shell from ubuntu terminal. If I was on unix I could zip the file with `zip filename.zip input1.txt` but this does not work inside the adb shell. Assuming this functionality is not installed.

Any solution to zipping a file from the adb shell command line?

I am running Ubunty 14.10 on the latop and connecting to a One Plus running Cyangenmod bacon.

Comment: I doubt `zip` functionality is available in Stock Cynogenmod. Do you have [Busybox](http://www.busybox.net/) ? Also check If you have `tar`.

Comment: No never heard of busybox. I'll look into that. Its for uploading to an existing web app so needs to be in zip. Might be able to look at zipping on the client side using Javascript though instead :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the SOLE objectvie is to ZIP file, you may fetch a file using  "adb pull" into your system.

ZIP the file using Ubuntu's ZIP Utility, and then simply "adb push" (means send the file back into device) the Zipped file.

Of course, in this case, you are using your System (and not Android device) to actually ZIP a File.

Comment: That might be the way I have to do it. Just trying to simplify the steps but I might have to teach myself to bash scripting to automate the whole thing anyway

Comment: If there is way you can "install" ZIP Utility into your device, then its fine, otherwise 1. "adb pull" <unzipeddfile> 2. ZIP and 3. "adb push" <zipped-file> is next option I guess.

Comment: I've ended up going this way and added an alias to my bashrc to string the three commands together to pull, zip, push then cleanup the leftovers. Makes it seamless and gets it all done in one command from bash. Thanks for the suggestion. Seems its the best answer considering busybox alternative doesn't support zip.

Comment: Great!! I myself used to follow the same and it does WORK.Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

A typical Android install will not contain a compression utility (zip or unzip). However you can install busybox for Android, which provides the zip and unzip utilities.
After that it would be as simple as:

```
adb shell unzip /sdcard/archive.zip
```

For this to work, you need to install busybox first.

1. If you're rooted you can directly install from
   [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en).
2. Otherwise, manually push the busybox app by first downloading the binary from [github](https://github.com/Gnurou/busybox-android/blob/master/busybox-android) (click on raw to download it) OR from
   [here](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/binaries/latest/busybox-binaries.tar.bz2).
   And save it somewhere like `/data/local` and then invoke it. It should be something like:

> ```
> adb push /path/to/busybox-android /data/local/busybox
> adb shell chmod 0755 /data/local/busybox #Make it executable
> adb shell /data/local/busybox zip /sdcard/myfolder_or_file archive.zip
> ```

If you encounter troubles, CD to the directory containing the file or folder and then run the zip command from there.

The simple way is to just use a good file explorer and navigate to the folder or file and then long press for options, there should be an option for compressing. Use can use Astro file manager, ES file explorer among other useful apps.

Comment: By Default Busybox doesn't support `zip`. You can use `tar` which is available in Busybox by default.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, they busyboxes don't support it anymore you can use one of these formats instead: tar, gz, bz. Even better just use another command-line zipping application like [zip-for-android](https://code.google.com/p/zip-for-android/downloads/list).

Comment: Yes. I agree, IMO `tar` is a better choice over `zip`.